# How to check if struct timer_list is expired?

Tags: c, linux, timer, linux-kernel, open-source

I have a c structure with two 'struct timer_list' inside them. Both of the timer_list calls the same call back function after they are expired. In the call back function, is there a method to find which timer has expired. One more thing, does timer_pending(&tmp->timeout) serve this purpose or will it only give the output whether the timer has at least started once or not and not if the timer is expired. The code suggests that it only checks .next field is NULL or not. Please provide me some insights.

```
struct tmp {
   struct timer_list a;
   struct timer_list b;
}

/*Both the timer calls function func upon expiry and passes stuct tmp as 
argument*/

static void func(unsigned long x) {
   struct tmp *tmp1 = (struct tmp *)x;
   //Find out whether timer a or timer b has expired.
}
```

Comment: It's really important to include *some* code to illustrate your problem, not just talk about it in generalities.

Comment: but what is `struct timer_list` ? if it's an homework, please show the exercice and show your effort to answer it.

Comment: struct timer_list is a standard structure defined in /include/linux/timer.h

Answer (score 0):

Warning: This question applies to an old interface of the Linux Kernel timer API. The timer interface has changed since commit:

```
commit e99e88a9d2b067465adaa9c111ada99a041bef9a
Author: Kees Cook <keescook@chromium.org>
Date:   Mon Oct 16 14:43:17 2017 -0700

treewide: setup_timer() -> timer_setup()

This converts all remaining cases of the old setup_timer() API into using
timer_setup(), where the callback argument is the structure already
holding the struct timer_list. These should have no behavioral changes,
since they just change which pointer is passed into the callback with
the same available pointers after conversion. It handles the following
examples, in addition to some other variations.
[..]
```

The answer I am giving, of course applies to old timer interface. The new interface is slightly different, and cleaner.

So, if you want to distinguish which timer is expiring then you shouldn't pass a struct such as `struct tmp` containing both timer to the `setup_timer` function.

In other words, according to your question, you are setting up the timers with something like:

```
struct tmp t;

setup_timer(&t.a, func, (unsigned long)&t);
setup_timer(&t.b, func, (unsigned long)&t);
```

You should instead be doing:

```
struct tmp t;

setup_timer(&t.a, func, (unsigned long)&t.a);
setup_timer(&t.b, func, (unsigned long)&t.b);
```

And then use `container_of` magic to go from the `struct timer_list` to `struct tmp`. I am only guessing this question is motivated by some kind of homework, so I will leave the rest as exercise for the reader. Enjoy learning!